# RSS Reader php (have already read related articles)

Tags: php, rss

Hey there. I've read all the related articles on here and can't find one that is specific to what I am looking for. I am new to RSS and am looking for the following reader if anyone know's the right direction to throw me in:

1. An rss reader that I can put on my page that does NOT require mysql database
2. A fairly light chunk of code that I can just add as many .xml,rss.php links/addresses to
3. I can wrap div's around to style each segment specifically as possible
4. can manually limit the amount of feeds that are read to conform to my desires of the pages content out put

thanks in advance!

Comment: You never specifically asked a question, but I'm assuming you're asking how to take a RSS feed and convert it into HTML for displaying?

Comment: Because I am not asking a question. I am looking for a rss reader that meets my specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its not clear to me if youre looking for a library to ease the parsing and conversion of the RSS to html out put or if youre looking for a standalone module you can just throw a number of feeds at and let it do all the conversion output internally.

Personally i would recommend the former as RSS isnt terribly complex and when combined with a good library to parse it its super simple. Id probably recommend [Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html) for this. Youll just need to write the logic to control it (ie. limiting the number of feeds and items from each and the dumping of the ouput).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Magpie](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) library which converts RSS feeds into arrays, making it easy to foreach the data, and then just wrap it up with whatever HTML you want.